# how to stop click event for Chart.js

Tags: jquery, chart.js, unbind

I have a small standalone html page that draws a barchart. 
I have put .unbind() on the canvas and enclosing  but the click and hover events are functioning; I had expected them not to.  Why?

Comment: Please share your code